# Finding the minimum bounding box of a rotated rectangle

Tags: javascript, performance, algorithm

```
function transformXCoordinate(x, xOrigin, y, yOrigin, theta) {
  return xOrigin + (x - xOrigin) * Math.cos(theta) - (y - yOrigin) * Math.sin(theta);
}

function transformYCoordinate(x, xOrigin, y, yOrigin, theta) {
  return yOrigin - (x - xOrigin) * Math.sin(theta) + (y - yOrigin) * Math.cos(theta);
}

function computeBoundingBox(x, y, w, h, theta) {
  let xCenter = x + (w / 2);
  let yCenter = y + (h / 2);

  let transX1 = transformXCoordinate(x, xCenter, y, yCenter, theta);
  let transX2 = transformXCoordinate(x + w, xCenter, y, yCenter, theta);
  let transX3 = transformXCoordinate(x + w, xCenter, y + h, yCenter, theta);
  let transX4 = transformXCoordinate(x, xCenter, y + h, yCenter, theta);

  let transY1 = transformYCoordinate(x, xCenter, y, yCenter, theta);
  let transY2 = transformYCoordinate(x + w, xCenter, y, yCenter, theta);
  let transY3 = transformYCoordinate(x + w, xCenter, y + h, yCenter, theta);
  let transY4 = transformYCoordinate(x, xCenter, y + h, yCenter, theta);

  let min_x = Math.min(transX1, transX2, transX3, transX4);
  let max_x = Math.max(transX1, transX2, transX3, transX4);
  let min_y = Math.min(transY1, transY2, transY3, transY4);
  let max_y = Math.max(transY1, transY2, transY3, transY4);
  
  return { x: min_x, y: min_y, w: max_x - min_x, h: max_y - min_y };
}
```

Test fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/qdu8kmv9/

I am looking to make this more efficient. I am using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622140/calculate-bounding-box-coordinates-from-a-rotated-rectangle) as a reference.

I tried implementing Troubadour's answer like so:

```
function computeBoundingBox(x, y, w, h, theta) {
  let ct = Math.cos(theta);
  let st = Math.sin(theta);

  let hct = h * ct;
  let wct = w * ct;
  let hst = h * st;
  let wst = w * st;

  if (theta > 0) {
    if (theta < 1.5708) { // 0 < theta < 90
      return { x1: x - hst, y1: y, x2: x + wct, y2: y + hct + wst };
    } else { // 90 <= theta <= 180
      return { x1: x - hst + wct, y1: y + hct, x2: x, y2: y + wst };
    }
  } else {
    if (theta > -1.5708) { // -90 < theta <= 0
      return { x1: x, y1: y + wst, x2: x + wct - hst, y2: y + hct };
    } else { // -180 <= theta <= -90
      return { x1: x + wct, y1: y + wst + hct, x2: x - hst, y2: y };
    }
  }
}
```

But it gave incorrect results. Am I converting it wrong or is his answer wrong?

Comment: The second bit of code you translated from Troubadour's answer assumes the rotation is around the bottom-left corner. Hence `y_min = A_y;` for a rotation in 0-90 degrees. The other bit of code you wrote rotates around the center of the rectangle. Obviously you can reduce computation for your first bit of code, you repeatedly call `Math.cos(theta)` and `Math.sin(theta)` (the `Math.min()` and `Math.max()` calls are trivial in comparison). Knowing that all corners are transformed in a similar way (they're all at the same distance from the center), you can simplify a lot!

Comment: Ah, I see.. I'd prefer to get Troubadour's answer working since it seems much more efficient. I'm not exactly sure how to change his snippet to make the center the point of rotation instead of the bottom left though.. Is it hard to do?

Comment: I suggest you sit and work out the math. It's just trigonometry. It's a good exercise! Also, I highly recommend that you don't take pieces of code from SO without really understanding what they do. You should have worked out the math using the answer and code you found, so that you understood why it works, and then you wouldn't have been surprised at getting different answers.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I'm still having trouble. Math was always my worst subject by far, and this is giving me a lot of headache trying to get working.

Comment: Fixing non-working code is off-topic for CR. Please see [on topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). -- _"Code Review aims to help improve working code. If you are trying to figure out why your program crashes or produces a wrong result, ask on Stack Overflow instead. Code Review is also not the place to ask for implementing new features."_

Comment: (Wherever you present something to get help correcting results too far from what's wanted, be sure to include enough input to reproduce the problem.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Avoid numeric inaccuracies

You can use the vector along the x axis calculated as `ct`, `st` to deduce the quadrant rather than use `Math.PI / 2` or the approximation `1.5708`
`ct >= 0` for quads 1 & 4 and `st >= 0` for quads 2 & 3

### Reduce complexity

Rather than calculate the width `{wct: w * ct, wst: w * st}` and height `{hct: h * ct, hst: h * st}`vectors in the same direction you can calculate the height vector rotated 90 CW `{hct: -h * st, hst: h * ct}`

Thus all the calculations after that are all additions, and the code is a little easier to read and maintain.

### Avoid redundant code

When a statement block returns it should not be followed by an else clause.

eg

```
if (foo) { 
   return bar; 
} else { 
   return foo; 
}
```

should be

```
if (foo) { 
    return bar; 
} 
return foo;
```

### Avoid repeated code

You return the same object 4 times. Use a function to create the return object. See rewrite;

### Rewrite

- Assuming that x Axis is along w and y axis is down  along h.
- Lacking an origin will assume that the rotation is on the point x, y.

```
function computeBoundingBox(x, y, w, h, theta) {
    const result = (x1, x2, y1, y2) => ({x1, y1, x2, y2});
    const ux = Math.cos(theta); // unit vector along w
    const uy = Math.sin(theta);
    const wx = w * ux, wy = w * uy; // vector along w
    const hx = h *-uy, hy = h * ux; // vector along h

    if (ux > 0) { 
        return uy > 0 ?
            result(x + hx, x + wx,      y,      y + hy + wy) :
            result(x,      x + wx + hx, y + wy, y + hy);                
    }
    return uy > 0 ?
        result(x + hx + wx, x,      y + hy,      y + wy) :
        result(x + wx,      x + hx, y + wy + hy, y);                
}
```

Using subtraction as it is a little bit quicker (No type check needed) and a little more compact.

```
function computeBoundingBox(x, y, w, h, theta) {
    const result = (x1, x2, y1, y2) => ({x1, y1, x2, y2});
    const ux = -Math.cos(theta); 
    const ny = Math.sin(theta), uy = -ny;
    return ux < 0 ? 
        (uy < 0 ?
            result(x - h*ny, x - w*ux, y, y - h*ux - w*uy) :
            result(x, x - w*ux - h*ny, y - w*uy, y - h*ux)) : 
        (uy < 0 ?
            result(x - h*ny - w*ux, x, y - h*ux, y - w*uy) :
            result(x - w*ux, x - h*ny, y - w*uy - h*ux, y));
}
```

Or without the return function

```
function computeBoundingBox(x, y, w, h, theta) {
    const ux = -Math.cos(theta); 
    const ny = Math.sin(theta), uy = -ny;
    return ux < 0 ? 
        (uy < 0 ?
            {x1: x - h*ny, x2: x - w*ux, y1: y, y2: y - h*ux - w*uy} :
            {x1: x, x2: x - w*ux - h*ny, y1: y - w*uy, y2: y - h*ux}) : 
        (uy < 0 ?
            {x1: x - h*ny - w*ux, x2: x, y1: y - h*ux, y2: y - w*uy} :
            {x1: x - w*ux, x2: x - h*ny, y1: y - w*uy - h*ux, y2: y});
}
```

### Example

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = 90, y = 75, w = 70, h = 25;
var x1 = 210, y1 = 75;
function computeBoundingBox(x, y, w, h, theta) {
    const result = (x1, x2, y1, y2) => ({x1, y1, x2, y2});
    const ux = Math.cos(theta); // unit vector along w
    const uy = Math.sin(theta);
    const wx = w * ux, wy = w * uy; // vector along w
    const hx = h *-uy, hy = h * ux; // vector along h

    if (ux > 0) { 
        return uy > 0 ?
            result(x + hx, x + wx,      y,      y + hy + wy) :
            result(x,      x + wx + hx, y + wy, y + hy);                
    }
    return uy > 0 ?
        result(x + hx + wx, x,      y + hy,      y + wy) :
        result(x + wx,      x + hx, y + wy + hy, y);                
}

function computeAABBCenter(x, y, w, h, theta) {
    const ux = Math.cos(theta) * 0.5; // half unit vector along w
    const uy = Math.sin(theta) * 0.5;
    const wx = w * ux, wy = w * uy; // vector along w
    const hx = h *-uy, hy = h * ux; // vector along h
    
    // all point from top left CW
    const x1 = x - wx - hx;
    const y1 = y - wy - hy;
    const x2 = x + wx - hx;
    const y2 = y + wy - hy;
    const x3 = x + wx + hx;
    const y3 = y + wy + hy;
    const x4 = x - wx + hx;
    const y4 = y - wy + hy;
    
    return {
      x1: Math.min(x1, x2, x3, x4),
      y1: Math.min(y1, y2, y3, y4),
      x2: Math.max(x1, x2, x3, x4),
      y2: Math.max(y1, y2, y3, y4),
    };
}



function draw(x,y,w,h,a) {
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,x,y);
    ctx.rotate(a);
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0,w,h);
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}
function drawCentered(x,y,w,h,a) {
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,x,y);
    ctx.rotate(a);
    ctx.strokeRect(-w/2,-h/2,w,h);
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}
function drawBounds(bounds) {
    ctx.strokeRect(bounds.x1,bounds.y1, bounds.x2-bounds.x1, bounds.y2-bounds.y1);
}

requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
function renderLoop(time) {
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 150);
    const ang = time / 1000;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#F00";
    drawBounds(computeBoundingBox(x, y, w, h, ang));
    drawBounds(computeAABBCenter(x1, y1, w, h, ang));
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
    draw(x, y, w, h, ang);
    drawCentered(x1, y1, w, h, ang);
    requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);

}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: This is a good answer. Not sure who downvoted it but I assume the reason is that it still has the problem where it rotates around the bottom-left corner instead of the center, so it still has the same problems as the one in the original post.

Comment: @RyanPeschel Objects are normally rotated around an origin, in this case the origin is given by x, y.  If the OP wants to rotate around any of the corners set the origin x, y to the corner Eg bottom right  `computeBoundingBox(x + w, y  + h,  w, h, ang);`  top right `computeBoundingBox(x + w, y ,  w, h, ang);` and so on

Comment: Oh so if I want to get the bounding box of a rectangle rotated around its center I just do `computeBoundingBox(x + w / 2, y + h / 2,  w / 2, h / 2, ang);` ? Also, your code is giving me some errors like `xax` and `xay` are undefined. Any idea what those should be?

Comment: @RyanPeschel My bad I changed names and forgot to copy that to the second snippet. xax and xay are the unit vector eg x Axis x and x Axis y. Will fix now

Comment: Hey thanks for the fix. Was my most recent question about the bounding box correct though? Because I'm trying `computeBoundingBox(x + w / 2, y + h / 2,  w / 2, h / 2, ang);` with your code and it's still not giving me the correct bounding box. Sorry but I'm just really struggling with this (trying to get the bounding box of a rectangle rotated around its center)

Comment: @RyanPeschel Please note this is code review. We review code and the rewrites will match the code given. You are asking for a fix which is off topic. The code in the answer will only work for origins at the extremas (one of four corners). The linked question at SO (accepted answer)  shows how to get bounds for any origin. I have added in example how to get AABB when origin in at center (ONLY WORKS FOR CENTER!). To get AABB for any origin use the linked SO accepted answer.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I initially didn't realize the limitations of Troubadour's answer because it was presented as if it were just a direct alternative, so I thought I was just doing something wrong. In any case, I _still_ am having trouble with your code snippet. Maybe I should just make a stackoverflow post at this point.. Here's my fiddle in case you can spot the error. If not I'll just make another post https://jsfiddle.net/yw6k0tvz/

Comment: Ended up just posting another question here since I realize this has gone off-topic. I'll accept your answer in the interim and give you an upvote as well since I think it's rude that you've been downvoted considering how much you've helped already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69147768/efficient-way-to-calculate-the-bounding-box-of-a-rotated-rectangle